# Problem getting documents path with non-english characters

Tags: c++, c

The following function works fine when returning the Windows documents path if it contains all English characters; but returns gibberish if the path contains non English characters, such as Japanese.  Any solutions to this problem?

```
DLLEXPORT char* GetDocPath()
{
    wchar_t Folder[1024];
    HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderPathW(0, CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, 0, 0, Folder);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        char str[1024];
        wcstombs(str, Folder, 1023);
        return str;
    }
    else return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thou shalt not return a local array. They [decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) and you're stuck with a pointer to invalid storage.

Comment: Firstly, `str` is local, and returning it will cause Undefined Behaviour in the caller. Secondly, what is the gibberish and how do you show it? Oh, and thirdly, what is your locale?

Comment: Sorry, last one - fourthly: you should check the return value of `wcstombs` - did it succeed?

Comment: Additionally, `wctombs` uses the system default charset (locale). Are you sure your system codepage contains Japanese? Consider `WideCharToMultiByte` instead, it contains the codepage as a parameter. And yes, memory allocation.

Comment: Conversion from Unicode to mbcs is lossy. Keep it as Unicode to avoid round trip issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems in the past when using `wchar_t` to read french characters, and that is the type you are using in the `Folder` variable, I solved my problems using the plain `char` to read those characters, have you already tried that?

If you are on Windows maybe `char16_t` will do the trick.